# SSIS package SQL 2012 network access

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

We have an SSIS package that executes a .bat file.

The bat file does:

```
dir \\someserver\done\ > d:\scratch\ssisdir.txt
```

We have an storedproc that starts the SSIS package using the [start_execution](http://thinknook.com/execute-ssis-via-stored-procedure-ssis-2012-2012-08-13/).

If we call that storedproc from the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) it works fine.

If we call the storedproc from a web service (C# MVC) using the same credentials that SSMS, the SSIS reports that it doesn't have access to the path (network folder).

We have confirmed with SQL Profiler that the website is actually calling the storedproc with the same exact credentials.

Moreover, we added a call from the web service to do:

```
xp_cmdshell 'dir \\someserver\done\ > d:\scratch\testfromcmdshell.txt'
```

That works fine. It is the same connection that calls the SSIS, however, the SSIS doesn't have permissions.

Not sure what is missing or what else we can check.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So a couple of dumb questions: why not just kick off the batch file with xp_cmdshell? Why bother adding an additional layer with SSIS and the stored procedure?

Comment: And maybe a more helpful question: what happens when you run the catalog package using dtexec from xp_cmdshell? Does it throw you any errors then?

Comment: I believe the error is a gap in permissions between the invocation of the web service and the batch file's execution. Can you add a line in the batch file to echo out the %USERDOMAIN% and %USERNAME% to a text file? Just to see exactly what account is trying to run that command.

Comment: Kyle: the batch sample is a simplified sample. It is not our business case, but we have simplified our issue (what I put in the case is real, we programmed that to test and it fails - but it is not what we are trying to resolve). About dtexec: we are trying to do that now to see what happens. About %userdomain%: yes, we did that too before - it is the same user. Thank you.

Comment: To confirm: using xp_cmdshell 'dtexec... ' works correctly. We'll keep it like that, however, it is a mistery why it doesn't work correctly with the SSIS new execution procedures of SQL2012.

Comment: is the web service on a different server? There may be a problem passing the credential if Kerberos and impersonation are not configured correctly.

Comment: @Bill: it is another server, but we are not impersonating. We are using the credentials from the App Pool (a fixed user). So I do not think Kerberos applies in this case. Also, the same exact setup works if we use xp_cmdshell and dtexec to call the SSIS package (which is what we did - we didn't want to, but it works like that).